# How to change the innerHTML of a div in the main page according to the div value in the included page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have included a file named test.php in the file index.php

lets assume index.php is like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="dash">Index</h1>

<div id='tab.php'>

<?php include('tab.php'); ?>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and tab.php is like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul>

<li id='date' onClick="change_head(this.id);">Dates</li>

<li id='appoint' onClick="change_head(this.id);">Appointments</li>

<ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here what i would like to do is, if the list item date is clicked(list items are actually tabs). The inner html of the h1 tag with id dash should be changed to Dates and if the list item appoint is clicked the inner html of same h1 tag with id dash should change to appointments.

how can i do that ?? i tried the usual javascript way by taking the ids and applying the if condition to change the innerHTML but it was not working..anyone pls help me how to do it

### JAVASCRIPT (this is the js i tried to achive it...i added this in index.php)

```
    function change_head(id){

    dash = document.getElementById('dash').innerHTML;

    if(id == date){

    dash = "Date";


    }
    else if(id == appoint){

    dash = "Appointment";

    }
    else{
    dash = "Index";
    }

}
```

Comment: If you include tab.php in index.php the result output to the browser will have the html, head, body, etc. tags from tab.php all nested inside the html and body tags of the index.php. You should _not_ do that: the included page should be more of an html fragment (without all the html, head, body tags).

Comment: @Kiran added what i tried...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using jquery... something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li#date").click(function () {
        $("h1#dash").val("Dates");
    });
    $("li#appoint").click(function () {
        $("h1#dash").val("Appointments");
    });
});

</script>
```

Of course, if you had more of these tabs, I would create a single click event handler for all "li" elements and switch on the ID :-)

Assuming you're new to jquery, you'd also have to include the jquery script in your page.  Something like:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check out jquery.com to get started.

Comment: in which file i should add this ? index.php or tab.php ?

Comment: either one.  the javascript will be executed when the page is rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it with JavaScript (i.e. without page reloading), so you need use DOM `innerHTML`.

Something like (if you didn't use jQuery), didn't test this code through, hope you get idea:

```
var changetext = function(e,t) {
  e.innerHTML = t;
},
    elemheader = document.getElementById('dash'),
    elemdate = document.getElementById('date'),
    elemappoint = document.getElementById('appoint');

if (elemdate.addEventListener) {
    elemdate.addEventListener('click',changetext(elemheader,'Date'),false);
}

if (elemappoint.addEventListener) {
    elemappoint.addEventListener('click',changetext(elemheader,'Appoint'),false);
}
```